# Android: Null Pointer Exception Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference

Tags: android, sqlite

I am a beginner working with Android studio. I have an assignment at hand where I am supposed to use the spinner control containing choices to fetch database records from a books.db such as records with highest and lowest values, record count etc.
Below are my Main class and SQLHelper classes listing the details.
I keep getting this Null Pointer Exception everytime I try to run the code. I have literally tried everything but nothing seems to work!

Can someone please help?

**Main Class**

```
    package com.example.amrapali.bookreviews;

    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.Spinner;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.Comparator;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Set;


    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener, OnItemSelectedListener {


        SqlHelper db;

        boolean blnFlag=false;

        private String tag = "My Name Is:";

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            Log.i(tag, "Amrapali");
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.spinner);
            SqlHelper db = new SqlHelper(this);

            /** CRUD Operations **/
            // add Books
            //db.addBook(new Book("Professional Android 4 Application Development", "Reto Meier"));
            //db.addBook(new Book("Beginning Android 4 Application Development", "Wei-Meng Lee"));
            //db.addBook(new Book("Programming Android", "Wallace Jackson"));
            //db.addBook(new Book("Hello, Android", "Wallace Jackson"));

            // get all books
            List<Book> list = db.getAllBooks();
            ListView listContent = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
            List<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();
            books=db.getAllBooks();

            //get data from the table by the ListAdapter
            //ListAdapter customAdapter = new ListAdapter(this, R.layout.itemlistrow,  books);
            //listContent.setAdapter(customAdapter);
            //Book updateBook = list.get(3);

            // Spinner element
            Spinner spinner;

            // Spinner    element
            spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

            // Spinner Drop down element items (some list you build)
            List<String> blist = new ArrayList<String>();

            blist.add(0,"Select Analytics...");
            blist.add(1,"Get Highest Rated Title(s)");
            blist.add(2,"Get Lowest Rated Title(s)");
            blist.add(3,"Get Record Count");
            blist.add(4,"Retrieve Title(s) with Android 4");

            // Creating adapter for spinner, pass your list into the constructor
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, blist);

            // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.myspinner);

            // attaching data adapter to spinner
            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

            // Spinner click listener
            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        }     //end  onCreate() method

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id)  {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if(blnFlag)   //spoof message from displaying initially
            {
                if(position==1)
                {
                    String condition = parentView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Highest Rating =  " + db.getHighestRating(condition), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
                //get query result for Highest rated title(s)

                //display query result(s) in a Toast message

                if(position==2) {

                    String condition = parentView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Lowest Rating =  " + db.getLowestRating(condition), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    //get query result for Lowest rated title(s)

                    //display query result(s) in a Toast message
                }
                if(position==3)
                {
                    String condition = parentView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Total Number of Records =  " + db.getCount(condition),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }
            blnFlag=true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?>   parentView)  {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
        // update one book
        //int j = db.updateBook(updateBook,"Hello, Android","Ben Jackson");

        // delete one book
        //db.deleteBook(list.get(0));

        // get all books
        //db.getAllBooks();

        //Log.d("The book count is ", Integer.toString(db.getIds(updateBook)));
    }
```

**SQLHelper Class:**

```
    package com.example.amrapali.bookreviews; /**
     * Created by Amrapali on 4/3/2016.
     */
    import java.util.HashSet;
    import java.util.LinkedList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Set;

    import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
    import android.util.Log;

    import com.example.amrapali.bookreviews.Book;

    public class SqlHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        //Database Version
        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 4;
        // Database Name
        private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "BookDB";

        // Books table name
        private static final String TABLE_BOOKS = "books";

        // Books Table Columns names
        private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
        private static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
        private static final String KEY_AUTHOR = "author";


        public SqlHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // SQL statement to create book table
            String CREATE_BOOK_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE books ( " +
                    "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                    "title TEXT, "+
                    "author TEXT )";

            // create books table
            db.execSQL(CREATE_BOOK_TABLE);
        }
        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // Drop older books table if existed
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS books");

            // create fresh books table
            this.onCreate(db);

            String upgradeQuery = "ALTER TABLE books ADD COLUMN rating TEXT";
            String upgradeQuery2 = "ALTER TABLE books ADD COLUMN imagename TEXT";
            if (oldVersion == 3 && newVersion == 4){
                db.execSQL(upgradeQuery);
                db.execSQL(upgradeQuery2);
            }

        }

        /*CRUD operations (create "add", read "get", update, delete) */

        public void addBook(Book book){
            Log.d("addBook", book.toString());
            // 1. get reference to writable DB
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

            // 2. create ContentValues to add key "column"/value
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(KEY_TITLE, book.getTitle()); // get title
            values.put(KEY_AUTHOR, book.getAuthor()); // get author

            // 3. insert
            db.insert(TABLE_BOOKS, // table
                    null, //nullColumnHack
                    values); // key/value -> keys = column names/values

            // 4. Close dbase
            db.close();
        }
        // Get All Books
        public List<Book> getAllBooks() {
            List<Book> books = new LinkedList<Book>();

            // 1. build the query
            String query = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_BOOKS;

            // 2. get reference to writable DB
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

            // 3. go over each row, build book and add it to list
            Book book = null;
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    book = new Book();
                    book.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                    book.setTitle(cursor.getString(1));
                    book.setAuthor(cursor.getString(2));
                    book.setRating(cursor.getString(3));
                    book.setImageName(cursor.getString(4));

                    // Add book to books
                    books.add(book);

                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }

            Log.d("getAllBooks()", books.toString());

            return books; // return books
        }
        // Updating single book
            public int updateBook(Book book, String newTitle, String newAuthor) {


            // 1. get reference to writable DB
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

            // 2. create ContentValues to add key "column"/value
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put("title", book.getTitle()); // get title
            values.put("author", book.getAuthor()); // get author

            // 3. updating row
            int i = db.update(TABLE_BOOKS, //table
                    values, // column/value
                    KEY_ID +" = ?", // selections
                    new String[] { String.valueOf(book.getId()) }); //selection args
            // 4. close dbase
            db.close();
            Log.d("UpdateBook", book.toString());
            return i;

        }
        // Deleting single book
        public void deleteBook(Book book) {

            // 1. get reference to writable DB
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

            // 2. delete
            db.delete(TABLE_BOOKS,
                    KEY_ID + " = ?",
                    new String[] { String.valueOf(book.getId()) });

            // 3. close
            db.close();

            Log.d("deleteBook", book.toString());
        }

        public int getIds(Book book){

            String selectQuery = "Select id from books";
            SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor c = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
            c.moveToFirst();
            int total = c.getCount();
            return  total;

        }

        public Set<String> getTitle()
        {
            Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
            String selectQuery= "select * from " + TABLE_BOOKS;
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor  = db.rawQuery(selectQuery,null);
            if
                    (cursor.moveToFirst())
            {
                do
                {
                    set.add(cursor.getString(1));
                    //get title  column's  value
                }
                while
                        (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            cursor.close();
            db.close();
            return
                    set;
        }

        public int getCount(String condition) {

            int total=0;
            if (condition=="Get Record Count")
            {
                String selectQuery = "Select Count(*) from" + TABLE_BOOKS;
                SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
                Cursor c = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
                c.moveToFirst();
                total= c.getCount();
            }
            return total;
        }


        public StringBuilder getHighestRating(String condition) {
            StringBuilder s = null;
            if (condition == "Get Highest Rated Title(s)") {
                s = new StringBuilder();
                String selectQuery = "select max(rating) from " + TABLE_BOOKS;
                SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
                Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        s.append(cursor.getString(3)); //get rating's value
                    }
                    while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }
                cursor.close();
                db.close();
            }

                return s;

        }

        public StringBuilder getLowestRating(String condition) {
            StringBuilder s = null;
            if (condition == "Get Highest Rated Title(s)") {
                s = new StringBuilder();
                String selectQuery = "select min(rating) from " + TABLE_BOOKS;
                SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
                Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        s.append(cursor.getString(3)); //get rating's value
                    }
                    while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }
                cursor.close();
                db.close();
            }

            return s;

        }

    }
```

Comment: S.O. is not an on-demand debugging service: it is about solving specific programming problems, well defined by small examples. Find the minimal amount of code that reproduces the problem and then ask a more pointed question.

Comment: You are creating a new instance of SqlHelper on onCreate and using a global instance of SqlHelper  (db) throughtout the funtions which is never initialized.So you will not get crashes in onCreate but will get NPE in every other funtions.

Answer (score 1):

You have not initialized  the SqlHelper db which is global. Thats why your getting this error.

Change this

```
  SqlHelper db = new SqlHelper(this);
```

to

```
  db =  new SqlHelper(this);
```